# How to hide ldap password in ejabberd

Tags: ldap, ejabberd

I have recently started using ejabberd and I am setting up the ldap module. There is a line {ldap_password, "secret"}. Where it is asking for my ldap password in plain text is there a way of hiding this like putting it in another file then linking. I don't feel comfortable just putting my ldap password in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you ensure that:

- the config file is not visible by anyone but ejabberd (and root)
- ejabberd has its own credentials for LDAP, which can even be limited to only doing what ejabberd needs to do

A separate file provides no more security than above.

Having a dedicated LDAP user/password for ejabberd means that even if a compromise does happen, you can reset the password and only affect one service. If you do see some random connection in LDAP, it's also a good and simple way to figure out WHAT was compromised.